# Should you always create the mobile version of your site in a different project?

Tags: asp.net, mobile

Many modern web applications have a mobile/tablet friendly version. There's a convention I've seen many times to have the address http://m.somedomain.com as the mobile version of the http://www.somedomain.com. However from a .NET perspective this implies that these are created as different projects which can create overhead in terms of testing, deployment and often hosting costs.

When is it advisable to use a separate project for your mobile site and when should a folder within your project be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's a common solution for websites that doesn't support **responsive design** or we could say **legacy pc websites**, that's a common approach create a new website and do a "separate" web site for a mobile / tablet device.

Other reason could be that they may want to be mobileOK in this case the page is analized by several tests that may include HTML / CSS / and many other specifications for mobile devices, you can take a look to [mobileOK checker by W3C](http://validator.w3.org/mobile/) I think that a responsive design isn't going to pass that test.

Aiming to **feature phones** instead **smartphones** you can tailor a very basic plain vanilla HTML/CSS website that could support older devices, remember that some old devices may not support javascript, CSS3 or HTML5

***CONS:***

- you need to intercept the request at a web server level and do a
  redirect depending on the user agent
- Double effort on SEO you need to mark the mobile urls as cannonical to avoid a duplicated content
- Double effort by measuring the traffic (mobile and desktop/laptop)
- Double effort by developing and doing the maintenance of the website

All depends on what you need, if you have the chance to do a responsive design I'd suggest to follow that path.

Answer (score 2):

**It depends a lot on the design of the website.**

Most web developers and designers are creating their websites using  [Responsive Web Design](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/responsive-design/info), which allows to show the same content of the website, on many different sizes, like phones, tablets, or desktops.

This is done through a CSS3 module called [Media Query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_queries), and it haves to be implemented on the same project. This avoid the use of subdomains or different projects to show specific versions of the site. You can see a lot of examples on http://mediaqueri.es/.

In other side, if you can't implement `Responsive Design` to your site, you will have to create a new project, pointed from a subdomain (like `http://m.somedomain.com`), or called from a different route (like `http://www.somedomain.com/m/`). It is safe to have this new version on a folder within your project, and I would prefer this to reduce hosting costs.